# c++ fltk - loading images

Tags: c++, fltk

I don't know what is going on, I've included all libraries that are needed.
There are 2 errors that I am getting:

> unresolved externals(LNK1120) and unresolved external symbol(LNK2019).

The error comes in this line:

```
Fl_PNG_Image* mypng= new Fl_PNG_Image(name);
```

How do I solve this?

```
#include FL/Fl.H
#include FL/Fl_Window.H
#include FL/Fl_Box.H
#include Fl/Fl_Button.H
#include FL\Fl_Check_Button.H
#include Fl/Fl_PNG_Image.H

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const char* name = "2222";
    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(300, 180,"to dopiero poczatek");
    Fl_Box box(10, 10, 720 - 20, 486 - 20);
    Fl_PNG_Image* mypng= new Fl_PNG_Image(name);
    //box.image(mypng);
    window->begin();
    Fl_Check_Button *akuku = new Fl_Check_Button(20, 30, 40, 40, 0);
    char a = akuku->value();
    window->end();
    window->show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: Using `#include` in the source code isn't enough...you also have to set up the project to link with the necessary files or libraries.   The error message you're getting sounds like you haven't done that part.

Comment: at the beginning in Linker input I've added fltk.lib
fltkimages.lib, i have no idea what's missing